# Adding new method to JScrollPane with prototype

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototype, jscrollpane

I'm include some libs

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>

  <!-- the mousewheel plugin - optional to provide mousewheel support -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mousewheel.js"></script>

  <!-- the jScrollPane script -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.jscrollpane.js"></script>
```

Then want to add a new method

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    JScrollPane.prototype.putClientProperty = function(propertyName, elementId){

    ...
    };
</script>
```

And receive: *JScrollPane is undefined*. 
What i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You receive the error because JScrollPane is not a property of the window/global object but is added to `jquery.prototype` / `jquery.fn`. So, you should use:

```
jquery.fn.JScrollPane.prototype.putClientProperty = function(propertyName, elementId){

...
};
```

Comment: btw, this probably won't work as you want if you are doing what i think you are doing - extending the plugin by adding your own methods...I haven't had much experience with plugins, so to me the only way seems to hack the script file of the plugin